# Django: Create superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to define my own user module by following the documentation, but I receive the following error message whenever I try to create my first super user.

```
TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'
```

Some people seem to have solved it by commenting user.is_staff and user.is_admin but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

# Create your models here.

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not first_name or last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first and last name")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        #user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        #user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # Stupid name in Django - Basically is the "Login field"
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add password as argument in create_superuser body

```
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name):
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
    )
```

and I suggest to use the Django method `user.set_password(user.password)` before save because it hashes the password for you

```
    def create_superuser(self, password, email, first_name, last_name):
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
    )
    user.set_password(user.password)
    #user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    #user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed!

Comment: you mean you entered them but then Django throws an error because you not do? @massideux

Comment: you have problem here `if not first_name or last_name:` it should be 
` if  not ( first_name and last_name ) : `

Comment: Yeah noticed and that was indeed the problem, I think I am at the "last" issue now. The superuser gets created successfully but I can't login to the admin panel somehow, it says " Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

Comment: try uncomment this line `#user.is_staff = True`

Comment: ok, first you open the database if it's SQLite to check if the user is stored .. then try to create a new user... I think it's a keyboard problem, not a Django problem

Comment: Users are being stored, hashed passwords. Strange...

Comment: I noticed that it is user.set_password(user.password) that mess it up, when I changed back to password=password it works. But I can't see a user table once I login to the admin panel... Annoying

Comment: update the code in question and let me check

Comment: Solved by editing admin.py, and "password=password," in the original code in my post seem to hash the passwords. Despite not using user.set_password(password). Isn't that weird?

Comment: no, it will work if you did not hash your password ... but it should work if You use it also

Answer (score 3):

Add password to `create_superuser`'s arguments:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
```

Notice you are using `self` in `user = self.create_user(**fields)` so your function should have password arg too.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well!

Comment: it should. because you specified REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name'] in Account Class

Comment: Yeah sorry edited the comment, I think I used an incorrect if-statement in create_user class. Solved now!

Comment: I can't seem to login to the admin page though, " Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

Comment: notice raise ValueError("Users must have a first and last name")

Comment: Yes it creates the user successfully but I can't use the credentials to login apparently

Comment: well i can't help you for this situation. create a new superuser and try again

Answer (score 1):

Where you have the method:

```py
def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        #user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        #user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Do not do `password=password` in the `self.create_user` method.
Rather, do the following:

```py
user = self.create_user(
    email=self.normalize_email(email),
    first_name=first_name,
    last_name=last_name
)
user.set_password(password)
```

That method would take care of the password hashing and set it accordingly.